# Select and updating data from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I select data from my datatable, by using following code,but it throws an exception am not familiar with.

> "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

`tblRooms.Select(IDRoom = 4)`  This is the value of IDRoom in thetblroom but I don't know why it causes an error.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in tblRoomCart.Rows)
{

     DataRow drRoom = tblRooms.Select("IDRoom =" + dr["IDRoom"])[0];//here the error in this line 
}
```

Comment: Can you remove `[0]` and see what happens?

Comment: type of tblRooms it is table hotelid=10000 IDRoom=4 
hotelid=10000 IDRoom=3957  this the values inside the tblrooms

Comment: it gives me error when i remove [0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception says,Index is out of bounds,You are reading the first element (with index 0) but there are no elements in the collection.
It is the same as this:

```
int[] array = new int[0];
int x = array[0];//You will get an exception here
```

Add an if statement to make sure that there is at least 1 element,like:

```
int[] array = new int[0];
if (array.Length > 0)
{
        int x = array[0];
}
```